# USB connection from display detected as storage device

Tags: linux, usb, display, storage, block-device

I have an MSI Optix MAG245R 23.8" display. It features USB connections.

When I start up my Debian-based machine (BunsenLabs), I get warnings that say:

```
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.573980] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=4060, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.573986] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.573988] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.573990] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.673838] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.673846] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.673850] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.673852] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.673859] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
May  4 19:41:51 localname kernel: [  240.860367] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 1, async page read
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.500663] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=4060, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.612517] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=4060, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.697840] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.785872] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.818899] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=16348, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.909838] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:52 localname kernel: [  241.993839] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:55 localname kernel: [  244.842973] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=16348, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:55 localname kernel: [  244.942219] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:55 localname kernel: [  245.034140] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:56 localname kernel: [  245.473992] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:56 localname kernel: [  245.557874] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:57 localname kernel: [  246.425872] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unaligned partial completion (resid=2012, sector_sz=512)
May  4 19:41:57 localname kernel: [  246.425881] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
May  4 19:41:57 localname kernel: [  246.425884] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00
```

Then, I went ahead to launch GParted to inspect my storage volumes. I know what `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are; these are what I just expected.  Thus I was surprised why a `/dev/sdc` was detected.

[image]

There, Device Information says its an MSI Optix Driver.  I have tried isolating only the display's USB connection (no keyboard connections, dongles, whatever), and this is being detected as `/dev/sdc`.

What can I do to get rid of those errors?  My non-expert idea is to find some way to tell my machine that this device with UUID0123456789 is not a storage device, so don't bother testing it as a storage device.  How do I do that?

Or any other way?

Comment: The *interesting* part of `dmesg` is where the USB devices get detected. At least have a look at that to understand what's going on. Assuming the USB storage part isn't actually needed for anything, you can use `udev` rules to disable assignment of device node. Alternatively, you could use different `udev` rules to make sure it's not touched by partition detection etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @telcoM for the clues. I have fixed the problem.

## tl;dr

De-authorize the offending USB device using `udev` rules.

## How to do it

1. Run `dmesg` in follow mode:

```
$ dmesg -w
```

2. Disconnect and reconnect the display's USB cable.
3. In the output of `dmesg`, take note of the bus number of the device you want to disable (covered in yellow)

[image]

4. Exit `dmesg` with CTRL+C.
5. Now run the following to get the device attributes. Substitute `xxxusbxxx` with the bus number you got from `dmesg`

```
$ udevadm info -a -p /sys/bus/usb/devices/xxxusbxxx
```

6. This is the first part of the output, the one you care about. Take note of the following attributes and the path covered in the red box.

```
DRIVER=="usb-storage"
ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="aa"
ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="bb"
ATTR{bInterfaceProtocol}=="cc"
ATTR{bInterfaceSubClass}=="dd"
```

[image]

7. Now create a new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-disable-MSI-optix-storage.rules`.  The number `10` indicates that the rule is executed before other rules with higher numbers.  Keep the `.rules` extension.  The rest of the filename does not matter.  These should be the contents of the file.  Substitute strings accordingly.

[image]

8. Reboot your computer and see that the read error message no longer appear.

## What this actually does

When a USB device that matches the attributes specified in the `udev` rules file is detected, its `authorized` flag is immediately set to `0` and can no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

The display seems to be a dual-mode device, and the default mode is a storage device that contains a Windows and/or Mac driver intended for that device. More and more USB devices that need a driver seem to do that these days.

If you run `ls -l /sys/block/sdc`, you'll see it's a symbolic link to a path like

```
../devices/<PCI device path for the USB controller>/usb#/<USB device path>/host#/target#:#:#/#:#:#:#/block/sdc
```

... where #'s are numbers depending on your exact hardware configuration, and not important here.

You'll want to move to a directory just before the `host#` part:

```
cd /sys/devices/<PCI device path for the USB controller>/usb#/<USB device path>/
```

... and then see if the directory contains file named `bNumConfigurations` and `bConfigurationValue`. If it doesn't, move up one level (`cd ..`) and check again.

Once you find the correct directory, `cat bNumConfigurations` will tell you how many possible configurations (modes) the USB device has. A USB device that provides its own driver will most likely have at least two modes, so the command will probably output `2`.

`cat bConfigurationValue` will tell you the number referring to the current configuration. Most likely the storage device configuration is the first one, `1`.

To switch the USB device to its second configuration, run:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee bConfigurationValue
```

(or if you are running as root, just `echo 2 > bConfigurationValue`. Note the space between `2` and `>`, as `2>` has a special meaning to many shells.)

This should cause the "USB storage device" to vanish and be replaced with the actual functionality of the USB device in question.

To automate this process, most modern distributions have an `usb-modeswitch` component/utility. The fact that it did not already switch your device means you'll need to add information about your device to its configuration. Once you know the configuration number needed, you can create a text file at `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/XXXX:YYYY` where XXXX:YYYY is the vendor:product ID of the USB device that needs switching. The content of the file should be a line identifying the configuration you want. For example, if you found out that configuration 2 provides the actual functionality of the device, you'd write a line like this:

```
Configuration=2
```

And that's it. (You might actually want to send a copy of your file to the usb-modeswitch developers, so they can add the information to the future versions of the utility.)

Some devices may use a different switching method, which is more tricky to figure out. If the sysfs file `bNumConfigurations` indicates there is only one configuration for the USB device in question, you would need to e.g. build a Windows VM, present the USB device to it, install the driver offered by the device, and then snoop the USB traffic while the VM is starting up to capture the USB message sent by the Windows driver to the device to trigger the configuration switch. The `usb-modeswitch` utility can be configured to send such a message automatically, and its data files will include a number of existing examples of such cases.

Generally, a Windows "driver" for a display might contain little more than an `*.icc` colour calibration profile, which could be used in Linux too. If the display is optimized for high refresh rates (= a gaming display) or has weird color reproduction characters for some other reason, you might be able to improve the colour reproduction of your display by finding the colour calibration profile within the Windows driver package, and telling your desktop environment to use it with your display.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! Unfortunately, for `cat bNumConfigurations`, I only get `1`. Perhaps I could force it anyway, and write `2` into `bConfigurationValue`? On a different track, I'll try out the `usb-modeswitch` route.