WiFi 6 USB dongle only shows as single USB storage device
I have recently gotten a WiFi 6 USB dongle:

(this one)
Unfortunately, when plugging it in, I only see one additional USB device - and it's USB storage. When mounted, I see an .exe with, supposedly, a Windows driver installation executable for the WiFi dongle. dmesg log snippet below.
My question: Can I somehow "unhide" the actual network adapter USB device? Or is this dongle just out-of-spec and does its own thing and I can only use it on Windows?
[  933.907740] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  934.056360] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=a69c, idProduct=5721, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  934.056373] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  934.056380] usb 1-9: Product: Aic MSC
[  934.056386] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: aicsemi
[  934.056390] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: 20200203
[  934.058566] usb-storage 1-9:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  934.059002] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-9:1.0
[  935.076359] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     AIC      flash            1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  935.076940] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  935.077524] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] 15840 512-byte logical blocks: (8.11 MB/7.73 MiB)
[  935.077682] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is on
[  935.077689] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 03 00 80 00
[  935.077816] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page found
[  935.077821] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  935.080393]  sde: sde1
[  935.082889] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk


This question is similar to: How do I stop my USB-to-Ethernet adapter from presenting itself as a CD drive upon boot?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701431/usb-connection-from-display-detected-as-storage-device/701438 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722131/usb-ethernet-adapter-not-working/722142 and quite a few others.
